# How do I create a deflate file suitable for HTTP?

Tags: command-line, compression, http

Say I have `index.html`. How do I obtain `index.html.deflate` appropriate for serving through HTTP with the "deflate" encoding? I am coding a simple web server and I don't want to implement streaming compression. Apparently, deflate is supposed to be "raw" LZ77. Is there any command-line tool that does the encoding?

Comment: Update: Haven't tested yet but it appears at this time that `zlib-flate` is the appropriate tool.